# When I insert a USB, all other USB's get disconnected?

Tags: windows-7, usb, motherboard

I've got a few things connected to my USB ports.
Every time I insert a USB disk on key, my USB wireless device gets disconnected (the computer doesn't see it anymore at all).

I'm using windows 7, Gigabyte G41M-Combo MotherBoard.

I've tried several other USB disk on key devices. And several different USB ports.
Every time the USB based wireless device gets disconnected.

Any ideas what can cause this ? Or how to fix this even ?

**Edit:**

It used to work OK, it started when I changed my motherboard. (I've reinstalled all the drivers, both for the motherboard and wireless device)

The device is:  TP-Link , TL-WN422G ...

Comment: What sort of USB wireless device is this? Cell radio (WWAN)? Bluetooth dongle? WiFi adapter? Is this device internal to your machine or on an external port?

Comment: External - TP-Link , TL-WN422G ... It used to work OK, it started when I changed my motherboard. (I've reinstalled all the drivers, both for the motherboard and  wireless device)

Comment: I assume the usb wifi adapter you speak of begins to work again on reboot, then fails when you plug in a usb disk. What happens when you boot the computer with both plugged in (i.e. your wifi adapter and a usb disk)?

Comment: If i plug it in again it is detected again.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen problems like this one before. My guess is that your PSU (power supply) is insufficient. As soon as a new device with a relatively high voltage drain is connected, your +5V power distribution is overloaded, thus cutting power to the rest of the USB system. Try using another PSU and see if that helps!